# Rijndael C# to PHP conversion giving different results

Tags: c#, php, .net, encryption

I am trying to port an encryption code written in C# to PHP. The code below uses `Rijndael-128` encryption. The result given by PHP code is slightly different than the C# code. I am under constraint of not using `Salt` and Random `IV` and not altering `C#` code. After browsing through many of the answers on stackoverflow on this issue and making several changes to the code still the code is not producing correct result.

C# code (member function of a class)

```
public static string Encrypt(string plainText, string passPhrase)
{
    byte[] initVectorBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(initVector);
    byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
    var password = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passPhrase, new byte[8], 10000);
    byte [] keyBytes= password.GetBytes(keysize / 8); //256/8
    var symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();
    symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    ICryptoTransform encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes);
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
    cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
    cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
    byte[] cipherTextBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
    memoryStream.Close();
    cryptoStream.Close();

    return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes);
}
```

PHP code (member function of a class)

```
public function encrypt(){

    $plainText="Same_input_as_above";

    $plainText=mb_convert_encoding($plainText,'UTF-8');

    $passPhrase=mb_convert_encoding($this->secret,'UTF-8');

    $salt=str_pad("",8,"\0");

    $key= hash_pbkdf2 ( 'sha1' , $passPhrase, $salt , 10000 ,self::KEYSIZE/8, true);

    $initVector=mb_convert_encoding(self::INITVECTOR,'UTF-8');

    $tempCipher= mcrypt_encrypt (MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 , $key , $plainText , MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,$initVector);

    return base64_encode($tempCipher);
}
```

C# Output

```
O/Fi4tfdS5APen6YAboRnr%2B2bSrHSG71OHhX7YZbbhJYr8mt3HxfYza4bjkV8gtq
```

PHP Output

```
O/Fi4tfdS5APen6YAboRnr%2B2bSrHSG71OHhX7YZbbhIpdOLx9oscZnlAdyTMgeGX
```

The decryption function of C# works fine with the cipher created by itself but gives `Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.` error while decoding PHP generated cipher.

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt had many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution and are being maintained and is correct.

Comment: @ArtjomB. thanks. First I thought it was the empty salt that was making trouble after applying null padded salt I forgot to uncomment the plain-text padding lines after.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `mcrypt` only supports non-standard null padding. The C# library supports standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding. See [PKCS#7 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7).

You can easily add and remove PKCS#7 padding prior to encryption and after decryption, in PHP:

Add PKCS#7 padding

```
$padLength = $blockSize - (strlen($clearText) % $blockSize);
$clearText = $clearText . str_repeat(chr($padLength), $padLength);
```

Strip PKCS#7 padding

```
$padLength = ord($cryptText[strlen($cryptText)-1]);
$cryptText = substr($cryptText, 0, strlen($cryptText) - $padLength);
```

The better solution is not to use `mcrypt`. Options include [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor) which provide a complete solution.

Comment: thanks for suggesting better solutions, but while decrypting the removal of padding was not required